# Upgraded from 14.10 to 17.10 now getting strange /dev/nul file

Tags: files, 17.10

I updated Ubuntu from 14.01 to 17.10. Now I get a file named `/dev/nul` with the following text in it.

```
#############
error: conflicting format options

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
####################
```

How do I find out what is causing this file to be created. I delete the file but it comes back.

Comment: You probably have a cronjob or something that runs `ps` with some weird combination of options and outputs to `/dev/nul` instead of `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 2):

`ps` is a command line utility used to list running processes. It is common practice to redirect output of commands of which the output is not needed to `/dev/null`, which is like a Linux 'black hole' which allows anything to be written to it but when read gives nothing. By the looks of this something is running `ps` and redirecting the output to `/dev/nul` (i.e. someone made a type somewhere). The fact that `ps` is showing an error about conflicting options suggests someone made a typo there as well. It looks like it might be possible to use [`inotify`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file) to notify when the file is created/editied (you have to leave it there though and not delete it). Install it using

```
$ apt update
$ apt install inotify-tools
```

then try

```
$ inotifywait -m --format /dev/nul
```

and it should alert you when something edits it. It won't tell you what did it though. Try leaving it open in a terminal and seeing if it happens when you do or open anything in particular (or if ti just does it by itself).

Answer (score 2):

I ran `find . / 2> | xargs grep '/dev/nul' 2>` on the server to find all the instances of that string. I copied the results into a text editor. I replaced all `/dev/null` with blank. Then I was able to search for `/dev/nul` to find the problem file. It was a perl file that was installed as part of a package outside of the Ubuntu reps.
Thanks Aaron for the tip about `inotify`.